# ASP.NET MVC and ApplicationPath

Tags: asp.net-mvc, path, hosting, domain-name

Question is about paths and domains:

I have an out-of-the box ASP.NET MVC project (generated by "File->New Project").
On LogOn page it does: `return Redirect("~/Account/LogOn");`.

I have a domain name: `mycompany.com`, and following file structure on the server:

```
/Root
  /MyApp (this is where my app goes into)
     Default.aspx
     ...
```

I have set up following domain pointer: `mycompany.com -> \MyApp`

When I go to `mycompany.com` I get an error, something about can't find
`mycompany.com/MyApp/MyApp/Account/LogOn`

**Question:** Where does second `/MyApp` path element comes from?

*Note*: If I don't use domain pointer and deploy the site to the root - everything works just fine.

*Note*: My hosting provider is `webhost4life.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Try "return Redirect("/Account/LogOn")" instead.